# Select a value from a link

Tags: jquery, html-select

Is there a way to select special  item with jQuery by pressing button? In example bellow the value is 1,2,3,4... however it might a,b,c,d or red,green, blue. Is there a way without knowing the values of value?

For example :

```
<a id="item1" href="#">Item 1</a>
<a id="item2" href="#">Item 2</a>
<a id="item3" href="#">Item 3</a>

<form>
.......
<select id="items" name="items">
<option value="1">Colors</option>
<option value="2">Item 1</option>
<option value="3">Item 2</option>
<option value="4">Item 3</option>
</select>
</form>
```

If you press first the first button than in form automatically selects second option.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the buttons will have the same text as the `<option>` elements, you can use the [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector, as follows:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the selected item:
    $('#items option:selected').attr('selected', false);
    $('#items option:contains("'+$(this).text()+'")').attr('selected', true);

});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TZ464/)

Comment: is there a way to dynamically change id and link name according to select values? 
<a id="[FROM_SELECT_VALUES]" href="#">[FROM_SELECT_VALUES]</a>

Comment: i'm looking for a little bit different thing. Instead of ME putting <a>'s with values and texts can it do it itself while looping through the select values getting the quantity and value text and then create as many <a> tags with correct values and text needed.

Comment: as i said in original post i do not know how many select options i'm going to have or what are their values

Comment: @МодераторПлатформы This is a different question to the one you asked in the OP. Please ask it as a separate question on SO.